# Selenium : Alert handling

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, alert

I am trying to click on a button which will prompt a modern alert. But, I am getting "element is not clickable at a point " error.

```
    driver.get("https://letcode.in/alert");
    //send keys
    driver.findElement(By.id("prompt")).click();
    alert.sendKeys("Praveen");
    alert.accept();
    System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.id("myName")).getText());
    
    //modern
    driver.findElement(By.id("modern")).click();
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@aria-label='close']")).click();
```

If I do not perform the send keys prompt. The //modern alert works perfectly. I am facing this error after the execution of //send keys alert.

Please help

Comment: What's about your previous question?

Comment: Are you asking about the button one?

Comment: About the button color

Answer (score 0):

A good practice is to wait for element to be clickable before trying to actually click. Try adding a wait before clicking:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10); 
WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("prompt"));
element.click();
```

This will wait for 10 seconds for the element to be clickable before clicking.

You will need to import WebDriverWait and ExpectedConditions from org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.

Comment: Even with the wait, I am getting error as element interupted. The below comment worked for me.